# Change the value of a key in a nested json in plsql

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have a json like this:

```
"othervalue: "true",
"othervalue1: "ok",
"othervalue2: "cars",
        "carsmap": [
        {
            "modificationdate": "today",
            "carname": "Opel",
            "carstate": "true"
        },
        {
            "modificationdate": "yesterday",
            "carname": "Ford",
            "carstate": "false"
        },
        {
            "modificationdate": "today",
            "carname": "Mercedes",
            "carstate": "true"
        },
    ....
```

How can I do in PLSQL to change the value of "Mercedes" and set carstate to "false"?
I have a lot of BLOB like this in a DB column and I want to do this massively.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your JSON is invalid as you have opening `"` quotes and `[` array brackets and no closing quotes or closing array brackets and no surrounding `{}` object brackets.

Comment: Yes, true, I extracted only a part of thet big json

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 19, use `JSON_TRANSFORM`:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET value = JSON_TRANSFORM(
              value,
              SET '$.carsmap[*]?(@.carname == "Mercedes").carstate' = 'false'
            );
```

Which, for the sample data (fixing your invalid JSON):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  value BLOB CHECK (value IS JSON)
);

INSERT INTO table_name (value)
VALUES ('{
  "othervalue": "true",
  "othervalue1": "ok",
  "othervalue2": "cars",
  "carsmap": [
        {
            "modificationdate": "today",
            "carname": "Opel",
            "carstate": "true"
        },
        {
            "modificationdate": "yesterday",
            "carname": "Ford",
            "carstate": "false"
        },
        {
            "modificationdate": "today",
            "carname": "Mercedes",
            "carstate": "true"
        }
  ]
}'
);
```

Then, after the `UPDATE` the table contains:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| {"othervalue":"true","othervalue1":"ok","othervalue2":"cars","carsmap":[{"modificationdate":"today","carname":"Opel","carstate":"true"},{"modificationdate":"yesterday","carname":"Ford","carstate":"false"},{"modificationdate":"today","carname":"Mercedes","carstate":"false"}]} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KdpWmB_4)

Comment: 01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification". Depends on oracle version?

Comment: @ReDePasquale The first sentence of the answer states "From Oracle 19". Its been tested in Oracle 21 and 23 (there is not an Oracle 19 fiddle to test it with but `JSON_TRANSFORM` was introduced in Oracle 19 so it should work).

Comment: Yes I ask becouse I have 19c version but I retrieve from the query that ORA- error

Comment: @ReDePasquale I do not have access to your version to test it. However, the Oracle documentation for [`JSON_TRANSFORM`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/json_transform.html#GUID-DD2A821B-C688-4310-81B5-5F45090B9366) and for the [JSON path expression syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/json-path-expressions.html#GUID-AEBAD813-99AB-418A-93AB-F96BC1658618) looks like Oracle 19 supports everything in the answer. I get a similar error to you if I use Oracle 18 [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pYL1mQlh).